# How to create a video banner?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to know, how I can create a video banner in SharePoint Online? I tried to create by adding web-part but that is not in a format of banner. Each time I need to play video in order to see it, but I need like as an advertisement banner .

Answer (score 1):

Does the video need sound? if not perhaps you can find a way to convert the video into an animated GIF. Then it will animate and could behave like a banner so users can click on it go somewhere.

Sorry SharePoint's video play back is rather basic so I don't believe you will find much in regards to customizing it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any Autoplay feature present in SharePoint Online.

Videos from youtube or any other sites having autoplay feature can be embed

Comment: I found my answer. I needed just to check Start Media Automatically and Loop until stopped. That is simple answer for my question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [this](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/04/rotating-banner-in-sharepoint-2013-using-content-search-webpart.html) article.

You can add the video to a Document library, and follow the steps in the article, add it to the banner by the content search web part.